# Win 10 Remote Desktop Error - already have a remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I remote desktop to my Win10 it says "you a;ready have remote desktop connections on this computer"

:signed in for x days and xx hours"

How do I stop this message?

Remote desktop error:

[image: remote desktop error]

Comment: Are you sure you are supplying the same username and password on every connection attempt? Have you modified your system in any way? eg. patching the dll?

Comment: Yes.. same name/pass
No mod's

Answer (score 0):

Answer found HERE from https://johnlouros.com/

https://johnlouros.com/blog/list-and-kill-remote-desktop-connections

Let’s begin by opening the command prompt (or PowerShell) using: [Win] + [r]; type cmd (or powershell) and press [enter]

Now we are going to use qwinsta to (paraphrasing documentation) “ Display information about Remote Desktop Services sessions.”. If you use the command without any additional arguments, information about your local computer sessions will be display. However, most likely you want to target a remote computer; to do that simply enter the server name, or machine IP, using /SERVER: argument. Example qwinsta /SERVER:mywebserver or qwinsta /SERVER:192.168.1.15qwinsta screenshot

To disconnect, or reset a particular session, just use rwinsta and supply the server name and the session Id you want to reset. Session Ids are display on qwinsta resulting output. Example rwinsta /SERVER:mywebserver 70